# Processing data before saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have decimal field in my DB. Users can input values in two formats: with comma or point (11,11 or 11.11).

But MySQL allows to save data only in 'point' format, so i want to process data before saving with regex like this:

```
sub(/,/,".")
```

How can i do it in Rails3?

Comment: You want to validate data in model or in view?

Comment: No, data verified with validator and then go to controller's save method in two formats (with ',' or '.'). At this point i want to transform ',' to '.'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this could be done in the controller or the model.  I might use the before_save callback in the model to achieve this in the following way:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :standardise_numbers
  ...

  protected
  
  # Called before this object is saved to the DB
  def standardise_numbers
    self.number.sub!(",", ".")
  end
end
```

Where **number** is the attribute you're wanting to convert.

I assume you don't need to convert it back to comma representation to display to the user?  If you do, you may want to look into the internationalisation API for Rails, Il8n.  It handles this kind of stuff and more, so definitely worth looking into.

#### Alternative Solution (edit)

Based on your feedback, my above solution doesn't work since the number is already converted and the decimal part lost when it is passed into the model.  A similar piece of code could be used in the controller to intercept and convert the number in the params hash itself:

```
class PostController < ActionController
  before_filter :standardise_numbers, :only => [ :create, :update ]
  
  def create
    @post = Post.create(params[:post])
  end

  protected
  
  # Intercepts the params hash
  def standardise_numbers
    params[:post][:number].sub!(",", ".")
  end
end
```

This simplifies the create and update methods, allowing you to deal with the hash in the same way you normally would.

Comment: Model transforms original value to decimal and cut ',11' part, so `self.number => 11` (decimal) and i couldn't apply `sub` to it.

Comment: That makes sense, since ActiveRecord knows what data types the database is expecting it must cast everything accordingly.  You could use a `before_filter` in the controller to act on the `params[:item][:number]` directly, thus saving you from repeating that code in the create and update methods (and allowing you to call create/update with the `params[:item]` hash directly if you wanted).

Comment: Create a internal attribute to store the original form of the params[:post][:number] (you can do that when Item is constructed). Then you can use that in the before_save callback to get the value you need.

Comment: @JamesDS thank you for your help, alternative way works perfect!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help!  Dave Issacs' idea is also a good one - it would be cool to see an answer demonstrating how it would be done with an internal attribute.

Comment: @DaveIsaacs Can you show how to pass internal atribut with params from controller to model?

Answer (score 0):

I played this it and found this:

Suppose what in form field **number**, user inputs value '12,13'.

Value from form go to PostController to 'create' method

```
 class PostController < ApplicationController
 def create
   @post = Post.new(params[:post]) 
   #on this step instance of Post model created, validated and filled with relevant values
   #so @post.number == '12' #(decimal), it cuts ',13'
   #we need to redefine @post.number
   @post.number = params[:post][:number].gsub(/,/,'.').to_f # => 12.13
   #and after that save the post
   @post.save
 end
```